# Did Voldemort ever sleep after the 4th book?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

As Voldemort was a rather special Dark Lord, did he ever sleep since he returned in the 4th book? It seems to me that he didn't and needn't have to even.

Comment: This wouldn't be a smart thing to do in a book. Him being asleep puts him into an obvious vulnerable position which makes him less of a threat.  bare in mind that the best thing j Rowling does is truly tell the story through the eyes of Harry. From his point of view, there is no aparent weakness that he understands until the very end. Also it would be a red herring. The weaknesses to focus on are made clear in book 6. Sleeping is not what beats him at the end. I'm not saying this is off topic or something, but it's kind of equivalent to asking " why are the books not horrible and confusing ?"

Comment: @Raditz_35 I agree, and would also add that allowing the reader to witness Voldemort sleeping makes Voldemort vulnerable *to the reader* - and, thus, more implicitly sympathetic, rather than simply monstrous.  How many stories out there allow the reader to be present when the villain sleeps without making it a major part of the story one way or another?  If you let the reader get past the villain's defense, you have to make it matter.

Comment: Yes. He slept with the fishes at the end of *Deathly Hallows*.

Answer (score 4):

## We don’t know - it’s never mentioned whether the Dark Lord slept.

It’s never mentioned whether the Dark Lord slept or not, nor is it reasonably deducted from information we already have about him. Presumably when he was still Tom Riddle, he would have slept, but after he regained a body, we don’t know if he slept. He *did* mention existing sleeplessly when he was in spirit form, before having created any sort of new body for himself. He’d probably have needed to sleep up until that point, since he bothered to mention existing sleeplessly.

> “I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by second, to exist … I settled in a faraway place, in a forest, and I waited … surely, one of my faithful Death Eaters would try and find me … one of them would come and perform the magic I could not, to restore me to a body … but I waited in vain …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

However, after that he doesn’t mention whether or not he sleeps. Whether he did sleep would likely depend on how “human” his reconstructed body was, and if it needed or was able to sleep.

## As his new body was like his old one, it’s likely he did need sleep.

There is something that implies that the Dark Lord still would have needed to sleep, though it’s never said or shown that he does. After regaining a body, the Dark Lord states that the potion he used to create it would give him back a body like his old one.

> “But I was willing to embrace mortal life again, before chasing immortal. I set my sights lower … I would settle for my old body back again, and my old strength.
>
> ‘I knew that to achieve this – it is an old piece of Dark Magic, the potion that revived me tonight – I would need three powerful ingredients.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

As he seemed to have needed sleep before his being disembodied by the Killing Curse, since he mentioned existing sleeplessly, and his new body was like his old one in strength and mortality, it seems likely that the Dark Lord still needed to sleep after he regained a body with the potion.

Comment: Nor did he poop.